# PHP XOR Decryption

Tags: php, encryption, md5, xor

I have an encrypted parameter V coming from a web page like this:

```
page.php?V=5E5C535C584B40584A4A4E564B5D4503510755020402080C580A015D0D0A5A010206070C0E025C000F005D080E5F5D
```

*V* is encrypted like above:

*MD5* :

```
md5("a=login|password") = b90669a351161d0d74bed0e04d7b5eef
```

*XOR* :

```
password= "1234567899999999"
encryptedXOR = obj.XOREncryption(password,"login|password|b90669a351161d0d74bed0e04d7b5eef")
```

which gives something like:

```
encryptedXOR = 5E5C535C584B48584A4A4E564B5D4503510755020402080C580A015D0D0A5A010206070C0E025C000F005D080E5F5D
```

what I want here is the function to decrypt this '**ecryptedXOR**' using the *password*, so that I can get the:

```
login|password|b90669a351161d0d74bed0e04d7b5eef
```

here's what I've done so far:
http://pastebin.com/D9mzx82Q

Comment: You can XOR by the same "password" to get the original string

Comment: what language is that obj.XOREncryption in? If that's JS, then it's doing bitwise ORs of strings, unless it's actually a separator in a string and you're missing a `"` in it somewhere.

Comment: Nacereddine, you should post that as an answer.

Comment: @Nacereddine the 'password' is the key to encrypt/decrypt using XOR, and i'm asking how to do that "get the original string" !

Comment: @Crontab I felt it was too short to be a good answer. I did post it now, hopefully someone will post a better one with a nicer explanation.

Comment: @MarcB obj.XOREncryption is the way that the other person encrypt his strings, i only have to decrypt with the given private password

Comment: @Zonta see my explanation in my answer.

Comment: A XOR cipher, which is already unsafe, using repetition of key material. Please don't expect too much from it (such as actual security).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can XOR by the same "password" to get the original string.

**Edit :**

from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_cipher):

> a string of text can be encrypted by applying the bitwise XOR operator to every character using a given key. To decrypt the output, merely reapplying the key will remove the cipher.

So if your `obj.XOREncryption()` is doing nothing extra but a simple XOR, by applying the same operation a second time you'll get the original text :

```
decryptedXOR = obj.XOREncryption(password, encryptedXOR )
```

Comment: you edit your post every minute, bro, i've no clue about the XOREncryption function, the only thing i 've between my hands is: V parameter & the password of encryption/decryption

Comment: @Zonta `V` in this case is the encrypted string, you create a function (if you don't have it already, I assumed you did) that XORs the content of the `V` parameter with the `password` you already have and you will get the `login|password|b90669a351161d0d74bed0e04d7b5eef` you're looking for.

Comment: @Zonta: A simple XOR just loops through each character in the original string and XORs it with the corresponding character in the password. Pseudo code: `for i=0..length(input) { output = output + input[i] XOR password[i mod length(password)] }`

Comment: @mcrumley :thanks, it would be nice if you see my code i've pastebined before (http://pastebin.com/D9mzx82Q)

Comment: @Zonta starting from scratch is the way to go